# Error in rep(" ", len) : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r, invalid-argument

```
library(OneR)
library(RWeka)

loan_train <- read.csv("loan_train.csv")
loan_test <- read.csv("loan_test.csv")
loan_train <- optbin(loan_train, method = "logreg", na.omit = TRUE)
loan_test <- optbin(loan_test, method = "logreg", na.omit = TRUE)

#Task 1
loan_1R <- OneR(bad_loans ~ ., data = loan_train)
loan_1R

loan_JRip <- JRip(bad_loans ~ ., data = loan_train)
loan_JRip
```

Need some help with my code. I am able to run everything but for some reason, every time I print loan_1R, it gives me an error. Tried using traceback() but have no idea what it means. My csv file can be in the link below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1139FUSXUc_fdzgtKAleo5bGAtjcVGoRC/view?usp=sharing

```
Error in rep(" ", len) : invalid 'times' argument

In addition: Warning message:
In max(nchar(names(model$rules))) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> traceback()
3: cat("If ", model$feature, " = ", names(model$rules[iter]), rep(" ", 
       len), " then ", model$target, " = ", model$rules[[iter]], 
       "\n", sep = "")
2: print.OneR(x)
1: function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print")(x) 


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RWeka_0.4-37 OneR_2.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1    tools_3.4.1       grid_3.4.1        rJava_0.9-9       RWekajars_3.9.2-1
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Also, the `nchar` line is also not a bug, since extracting a list element with single square brackets keeps the names.

Comment: ie: `setNames(1:26, letters); names(vec[1]); names(vec)[1];`

Comment: Okay, you're right.  Have deleted the incorrect comment.

Comment: It is working fine for me as well

Comment: Could the original author post `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Still cant get the loan_1R to be printed.... it gives me the same error.

Comment: Placed in the sessionInfo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of testing i found out the problem but I have no idea why it is so. Think that it has something to do with the library(RWeka) package.... Placing library(RWeka) after the OneR code seemed to make it run. But this means i encounter the error only once i run the library(RWeka). Any workaround this?

```
library(OneR)

loan_train <- read.csv("loan_train.csv")
loan_test <- read.csv("loan_test.csv")
loan_train <- optbin(loan_train, method = "logreg", na.omit = TRUE)
loan_test <- optbin(loan_test, method = "logreg", na.omit = TRUE)

#Task 1
loan_1R <- OneR(bad_loans ~ ., data = loan_train)
loan_1R

library(RWeka)

loan_JRip <- JRip(bad_loans ~ ., data = loan_train)
loan_JRip
```